# How to load birthdays on fullcalendar.js plugin in c# asp.net

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net-web-api

i'm trying to load birthdays to fullcalendar.js. To my shallow knowledge, birthdays should be every year and say for example, I have these birthdays like this in my database birthday column (Note: I have used a shortdate format

- 9/18/2016
- 10/20/2016
- 10/28/2016
- 10/27/2016
- 11/2/2016
- 11/3/2016
- 5/4/1992
- 1/13/2017

Pulling these dates to my calendar plugin, I will only see the date 1/13/2017 birthday showing, the other ones would not show unless I go to their particular year e.g 10/28/2016 will only show cos it is year 2016, october 28 and of course these has to show every year. I should be able to see those dates on the present year but at their respective months and day of the month. My c# codes is below

```
public object GetCalendarData()
{
    var currentDate = DateTime.Now.Date;
    var birthDays = from e in _userProfileRepository.Table.ToList()
        where e.Birthday != null
        group e by e.Birthday
            into g
        select new
        {
            Date = g.Key.Value,
            Count = g.Count(),
            UserProfileIds = g.Select(x => x.Id).ToList(),
            Category = 1
        };

    var subscriptions = from e in _estateRepository.Table.ToList()
        where e.SubscriptionExpiryDate <= currentDate
        group e by e.SubscriptionExpiryDate.Date 
            into g
        select new
        {
            Date = g.Key,
            Count = g.Count(),
            UserProfileIds = g.Select(x => x.UserProfileId).ToList(),
            Category = 2
        };

    return birthDays.Union(subscriptions).ToList().Select(x=>new
    {
        x.Date,
        x.Count,
        x.Category,
        x.UserProfileIds
    });
}
```

this is my calendar directive

```
function FullCalendar($window, $filter) {
return {
    restrict: "EAC",
    link: link
};
function link(scope, element, attrs) {
    /*  Initialize the calendar  */
    scope.$watch('waiting', function (newValue) {
        if (!newValue) {
            var date = new Date();
            var d = date.getDate();
            var m = date.getMonth();
            var y = date.getFullYear();
            var form = '';
            var today = new Date($.now());
            var defaultEvents = scope.dashboardData.calendarData.map(function (item) {
                return {
                        title: item.count+(item.category == 1 ? " birthday(s)" : "Expired Subscriptions")),
                        start: item.date,
                        category: item.category,
                        className: item.category == 1 ? 'bg-primary' : 'bg-warning',
                        userProfileIds: item.userProfileIds
                    };

                };
            });
            $(element).fullCalendar({
                defaultDate: $.now(),
                slotDuration: '00:15:00',
                minTime: '08:00:00',
                maxTime: '19:00:00',
                defaultView: 'month',
                header: {
                    left: 'prev,next today',
                    center: 'title',
                    right: 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay'
                },
                events: defaultEvents,
                editable: true,
                //  droppable: true, // this allows things to be dropped onto the calendar !!!
                selectable: true,
                eventClick: function (calEvent, jsEvent, view) { 
                    switch (calEvent.category) {
                            case 1:
                                scope.openBirthdayListModal(calEvent.userProfileIds);
                                break;
                            case 2:
                                scope.openSubscriptionModal(calEvent.userProfileIds);
                                break;
                            default:
                        }
                }
            });
        }
    });
}
}

FullCalendar.$inject = ["$window", "$filter"];

angular.module("app").directive("fullCalendar", FullCalendar); 
var dashboardData;
```

How can I make the birthday show on the exact month and day as the user navigates back and forth the calendar in years

Answer (score 0):

You have to supply a separate event object for each year that you want to display the birthday on. FullCalendar doesn't know your data relates to a birthday, it just sees it as an event on a specific date. It only shows on those specific years *because you tell it the specific year in the event data* (as is required). You could decide how many years ahead and behind you might expect users to reasonably look in the calendar, depending on its usage patterns, and generate enough birthday event data for that range of years.

FullCalendar does have limited support for recurring events (where you supply one event object and tell it to repeat the event at a given interval) but unfortunately you can only generate daily or weekly recurrences at present, so it won't work for annual events such as birthdays.

As an aside, if your database is storing birthdays (as opposed to Date Of Birth) then it doesn't really need to store the year, because a birthday is not associated with a specific year. However, if you have got the person's Date of Birth, it would be better to store that, then you can calculate both their future birthdays, and their age at any given date, should you require that in future.

The only other thing I can think of to solve the recurring birthday problem might go like this:

1) Inject a javascript variable into your page which contains a list of all the birthdays expressed as days and months (without years).

2) Handle the ViewRender event of FullCalendar - https://fullcalendar.io/docs/display/viewRender/ . Every time the view or date range changes, check the dates being displayed against the list of birthdays. If any of the birthdays falls into the day/month range being displayed currently (regardless of the year), use the renderEvent method - https://fullcalendar.io/docs/event_rendering/renderEvent/ - to insert a new event onto the calendar for the correct day/month/year combination. (You might want to check that there isn't already an event for that birthday in that year, e.g. if the user has already visited that view since the calendar was rendered. To do that, you could add a field to your JS birthday object which can hold an array of the years for which an event has been rendered already.)

Comment: Woow, I love this bro. Thanks. I will try this

Comment: @IdowuMatthewDamilola that's great. If you find the answer has helped you, please remember to upvote and/or mark as the accepted answer - thanks :-)